# Check Enter Time is in Between Two Time Range in android

Tags: android, timepicker

Hello Friends i set time from time picker dialog so i want to check this time is in between specific range time or not.

**My Time Range is  11:30 am to 10:00 pm**

so i want to check that my enter time is in between 11:30 am to 10:00 pm or not.

**my code is as below.**

```
Calendar mCalendarOpeningTime;
Calendar mCalendarClosingTime;
Calendar finalTime;
 int hour,min;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        min = selectedMinute;
        finalTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        finalTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
        finalTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
        mStringGetTime = String.valueOf(DateFormat.format("h:mm aa",finalTime));


    }
};
```

**And i set opening time and closing time value as follow**

```
    mCalendarOpeningTime.set(11,30);
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(10,00);
```

**In my submit button click i set following code**

```
if(finalTime.after(mCalendarOpeningTime) && finalTime.before(mCalendarClosingTime))
                    {
                    System.out.println("Your time is in range");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your time is not in range");
                    }
```

so when i submit it it print message every time as **your time is not in range**  any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `Calendar` instances for `mCalendarOpeningTime` and `mCalendarClosingTime`, why dont you use them as `Date` instances?? that'll be more efficient and might as well get your code up and running.

**EDIT:-** ok.. forget whats written above.. It was crap.. :P following the piece of code that will do what you want to achieve:-

First up.. set the `mCalendarOpeningTime` and `mCalendarClosingTime` something like this and call this method in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` so that the values are assigned to the respective "times" before you start using them:-

```
private void setOpeningAndClosingTimes() {
    mCalendarOpeningTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
    mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    mCalendarClosingTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
}
```

your comparison is good enough.. try this and let me know if it worked or not...

Comment: do you have any code or link for that how can i convert Calendar instances into Date instances so i can get more idea about it?

Comment: :: It is working bro.. thnks for your post and your time i upvote your answer

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement your code in this way!!

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CompareTimestamp
```

{

```
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

    Calendar firstLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 20);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

    Calendar secondLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
    secondLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 21);
    secondLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    secondLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);



    if(finalTime .after(firstLimit)&&finalTime .before(secondLimit))
    {
        System.out.println("Its dinner time between 8:30 pm and 9:30pm");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No dinner right now");
    }

  }
  }
```

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: your code working fine but can i set AM/PM value in Calender  because my time format is 12 hour not 24 hour ?

Comment: I found my solution see answer of **@d3m0li5h3r** but i get hint from your post first so i also upvote your answer , thanks bro.. for your effort and time

Comment: I think it can be done:
firstLimit.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya:Welcome,,surely you can set AM/PM values using finaltime.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM or Calendar.PM);